# Convert OData to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, deserialization, odata

In response to

```
< script >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:37994/odata/EPStructures3/",
      type: "Get",
      contentType: 'application/json; odata=nometadata; charset=utf-8',
      success: function(data) 
      {
         var arr_from_json = JSON.parse(data);            
         //do something.....
      },
      error: function(msg)
      {
        alert(msg);
      }
    });
  }); 
< /script>
```

I am getting the following JSON

```
{"value":[{"eps_level":0,"id":2},{"eps_level":1,"id":3}]}
```

I want to convert it to a this (tried using JSON.parse(data)), but it is not working

```
[{"eps_level":0,"id":2},{"eps_level":1,"id":3}]
```

My Class is

```
[Table("EPStructure")]
    public partial class EPStructure
    {
        public byte eps_level { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column("eps_id")]
        public int id { get; set; }    

    }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `contentType` on a GET is meaningless - that's meant for POST values. If you add `dataType: "json"` to your ajax call, then the result you get back will already be a javascript object (assuming it's valid JSON), so you won't need to parse the JSON.

Comment: I don't get what you mean with 'convert odata to json'  (for me that doesn't really make sense!?)

Answer (score 2):

The returned data is in JSON format. So it's actually a JavaScript object (**J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation). You want to strip out the object containing the array with objects.

Just do the following:

```
var arr_from_json = JSON.parse(data).value; //parse it into a JavaScript Object, call its property value. This will return an array
```

Parsing it into JavaScript was correct. From then on you can treat the object normally and retrieve the properties from it. In this case the array is stored in the `value` property.

Working example:

```js
var data = '{"value":[{"eps_level":0,"id":2},{"eps_level":1,"id":3}]}'; //this line represents the object returned from the ajax call;
var arr_from_json = JSON.parse(data).value;

//you can access eps_level by doing this: arr_from_json[0].eps_level

document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(arr_from_json);// for demo purposes. This line is not part of the solution.
```

As Joe Enos commented: if you use jQuery functionality `dataType` here you can skip the `JSON.parse`-step, because `data` will contain the parsed JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who helped me find an answer to my question.

I resolved it by replacing

```
var arr_from_json = JSON.parse(data);
```

with

```
var arr_from_json = JSON.stringify(data.value);
```